# Array.sort function only working for a single criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I'm trying to organize by the value and then if they have the same value, alphabetically.

```js
function order(a, b, total) {
    if (total == 0) {
        return a.localeCompare(b)
    } else {
        return total;
    }
}

var thingsArr = {"lamp":2, "books":2};

Object.keys(thingsArr).sort(function (a, b) {
    order(a, b, thingsArr[b] - thingsArr[a])
});
```

Shouldn't the `else` (inside the function order) organize the resulting array alphabetically and the `if` organize by the highest value? It only seems to work when I use them individually.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to return a value inside the sort function!

Comment: You need to do `return order(a, b, thingsArr[b] - thingsArr[a])`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You can't sort the properties of an object.

Comment: Jesus...I knew it would be something really simple xD thanks! Answer the question so I can mark your answer as the accepted answer :)

Comment: In addition to what @TasosBu mentioned, you never do anything with the resulting array.

Comment: I guess this is not the full code of what you are trying to do right?

Comment: You could use arrow functions with implicit returns: `(a, b) => order(a, b, thingsArr[b] - thingsArr[a])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value inside the sort function!

```
function order(a, b, total) {
    if (total == 0) {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    } else {
        return total;
    }
}

var thingsArr = {"lamp":2, "books":2};

const result = Object.keys(thingsArr).sort(function (a, b) {
    return order(a, b, thingsArr[b] - thingsArr[a]);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to get an ordered list of names then you can improve the readability a little by moving the total calculation to your order function like:

```
const things = {"lamp":2, "books":2}; // not an array (thingsArr?)

function orderThings(a, b) {
    const total = things[b] - things[a];
    if (total === 0) {
        return a.localeCompare(b)
    }
    return total;
}

Object.keys(things).sort(orderThings);
```

But if you plan on then using the list as keys to reference your items the it might be worth considering mapping to an array of objects { name: "lamp", qty: 2 } or tuples [ "lamp", 2 ] you could do this like so.

```
const things = {"cupboard": 0, "lamp": 2, "books": 2};

function mapValuesToObj([name, qty]) {
    return {
      name,
      qty,
    };
}

function orderThings(a, b) {
    const total = b.qty - a.qty;
    if (total === 0) {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    }
    return total;
}

Object.entries(things).map(mapValuesToObj).sort(orderThings);
```

Returns:

```
[
  { name: 'books', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'lamp', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'cupboard', qty: 0 }
]
```

Hope this is helpful :) keep at it, you're doing great!

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to return value on array sort function.
You need to return negative, zero or positive int value depending on the argument and order result.

For more information, pls reference this url.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort